# Where is the fault?

Tags: c++11

complier error
    Error   C2440    '=': cannot convert from 'const std::basic_string,std::allocator>' to 'const char *'

```cpp
int main(void)
{

    /*
    complier error
    Error   C2440    '=': cannot convert from 'const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'const char *' 
    primer  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27706\include\xutility  1745
    */
    list<string> names = {"A","B"};
    vector<const char*> vnames;
    vnames.assign(names.cbegin(), names.cend());//OK
    /*for (auto it = names.cbegin(); it != names.cend(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }*/
    for (auto it = vnames.cbegin(); it != vnames.cend(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
vnames.assign(names.cbegin(), names.cend());//OK
```

Your comment says "OK", but it's not OK. You can't assign `std::string` objects to `const char*` ones. If you want to get the C string pointers of each `std::string` and put it into `vnames`, then you have to:

```
for (const auto& i : names) {
    vnames.push_back(i.c_str());
}
```

After that, you need to be very careful not to modify the `names` vector in any way that would cause a reallocation. Doing so will invalidate the pointers stored in `vnames`.

Comment: i made a mistake . const char * can convert to string but string can not convert to const char *.

Comment: My goal is to test whether the assign function can allow assignments from different but compatible types.

Comment: @user9981474 Then you should have asked that instead of "where is the error" :-)

Comment: yeah.I didn’t realize this error at the time.But thank you very much.And I don't quite understand the second sentence you said " be very careful not to modify the names vector in any way that would cause a reallocation. Doing so will invalidate the pointers stored in vnames." Can you give an example?

Comment: @user9981474 If you do something like `names.clear()` for  example, all the pointers in `vnames` will point to deleted memory.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `list<string> names ;
 vector<const char*> vnames = { "A","B" };
 names.assign(vnames.begin(), vnames.end());
 vnames.clear();
 for (auto it = names.cbegin(); it != names.cend(); ++it)
 {
  cout << *it << endl;
 }`

Comment: `const char*` is a pointer. You are storing pointers to the internal memory of `string` objects (that's what the `c_str()` function returns, a pointer to internal memory of the `string` object.) If the `string` objects are destroyed, the `const char*` pointers become invalid (called "dangling pointers".) @user9981474